# Pygame Collision doesn't detect as collision when detecting more rectangles

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, collision-detection

I'm making brick breaker on my phone, and encountered a problem.
When `ball rect` is in middle x of 2 bricks, it just ignores the side collision:

```
for brick in bricks:
    if brick.colliderect(ball):
        #side collision
        dr = abs(brick.right - ball.left)
        dl = abs(brick.left - ball.right)
        db = abs(brick.bottom - ball.top)
        dt = abs(brick.top - ball.bottom)
        if min(dl, dr) < min(dt, db):
            speed[0]=-speed[0]
        else:
            speed[1]=-speed[1]
```

It ***somehow*** detects collision with colliderect, but with side collision not.

Comment: @Rabbid76 But resultion is made only for my phone :(

Comment: @Rabbid76 its rect and it draws it as circle :(

Comment: @Rabbid76 The ball is rect. Resultion of whole game is made for my phone, with this I mean: all things are drawn 2 times bigger of the size it would be on computer. Resultion of my phone is around 900x2100.

Comment: @Rabbid76 If I want to make it reproducible I would need to remake it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your algorithm inverts the direction  of movement for each rectangle the object collides with. If the object collides with 2 rectangles in the same direction, the direction of movement at the end is the original direction. There may be several options 2 to solve the problem:

Attempt 1: `break` the loop after the 1st detected collision:

```py
for brick in bricks:
    if brick.colliderect(ball):
        #side collision
        dr = abs(brick.right - ball.left)
        dl = abs(brick.left - ball.right)
        db = abs(brick.bottom - ball.top)
        dt = abs(brick.top - ball.bottom)
        if min(dl, dr) < min(dt, db):
            speed[0]=-speed[0]
        else:
            speed[1]=-speed[1]

        break
```

Attempt 1: Do not invert the direction, but set the direction depending on the side of the collision:

```py
for brick in bricks:
    if brick.colliderect(ball):
        #side collision
        dr = abs(brick.right - ball.left)
        dl = abs(brick.left - ball.right)
        db = abs(brick.bottom - ball.top)
        dt = abs(brick.top - ball.bottom)
        if min(dl, dr) < min(dt, db):
            speed[0] = -abs(speed[0]) if dl < dr else abs(speed[0])
        else:
            speed[0] = -abs(speed[1]) if dt < db else abs(speed[1])
```